# Render list of array objects (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

I am stuck in one function. I'm trying to render **list of books** - this list is an **array of objects**. But before rendering it to the HTML, I have to check if all three properties are present in the object i.e **author, name and price** and render only those having all three properties. So I use `try...catch`. Then I use `map()` to create new array and render it. `Try...catch` block detects errors, but objects without errors are not displayed.
Here is my code:

```
function renderBooks(arr) {
    const list = document.getElementById("root");
    function makeElem(arrItem, arrIndex) {
        const {author, name, price} = arrItem;
        let li = document.createElement('li');
        if (!author) {
            throw new Error(`no author in book: #${arrIndex + 1}`);
        } else if (!name) {
            throw new Error(`no name in book: #${arrIndex + 1}`);
        } else if (!price) {
            throw new Error(`no price in book: #${arrIndex + 1}`);
        }
        return li.innerHTML = `<strong>Author:</strong> ${author}<br><strong>Name:</strong> ${name}<br><strong>Price:</strong> ${price}`;
    }

    arr.map((item, index) => {
        try {
            makeElem(item, index);
            return  list.innerHTML = `<ul>${makeElem(item)}</ul>`;
        } catch (Error) {
            console.log(Error);
        }
    });
}

renderBooks(books);
```

**UPD**: I have updated the code, now only first book is rendered, but all other eligible books are not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have updated your implementation to do what I think you wanted to do :-

```
function renderBooks(arr) {
    const list = document.getElementById("root");
    function makeElem(arrItem, arrIndex) {
        const {author, name, price} = arrItem;
        let li = document.createElement('li');
        if (!author) {
            throw new Error(`no author in book: #${arrIndex + 1}`);
        } else if (!name) {
            throw new Error(`no name in book: #${arrIndex + 1}`);
        } else if (!price) {
            throw new Error(`no price in book: #${arrIndex + 1}`);
        }
        li.innerHTML = `<strong>Author:</strong> ${author}<br><strong>Name:</strong> ${name}<br><strong>Price:</strong> ${price}`;
        return li;
    }
    const listContainer = document.createElement('ul');
    // Incase you don't know this, read about it. Helps from performance point of view for large DOM updates.
    const listFragment = document.createDocumentFragment();
    arr.forEach((item, index) => {
        try {
            const listElement = makeElem(item, index);
            listFragment.append(listElement);
        } catch (Error) {
            console.log(Error);
        }
    });
   listContainer.append(listFragment);
   list.append(listContainer);
}

renderBooks(books);
```

The way your current code is - there would be a certain amount of issues. Firstly would be to take consideration of adding multiple list elements. Setting `innerHTML` the way you have done it will certainly override previously added `li` elements and you will only see one. Also `.forEach` makes more sense here than `.map` since you don't have to return a new array.